# when I merge some .ts files using ffmpeg library and for making mp4 video it gives me errors

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, mp4, m3u8

I got `.ts` files from `m3u8` link and now I want to merge the `.ts` files. After searching I came to know that we can merge `.ts` files using `ffmpeg` library. Now when I try to merge after certain process it gives me error as following.

user this function for merging ts two mp4

```
WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.whizpool.muftatv/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress: ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
03-01 17:43:58.049 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
03-01 17:43:58.059 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
03-01 17:43:58.059 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
03-01 17:43:58.059 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress:   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
03-01 17:43:58.069 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress: [concat @ 0x41a66eb0] Impossible to open '/storage/emulated/0/Mufta/3117927975001_4221595953001_s-6.ts?'
03-01 17:43:58.069 23895-23895/com.whizpool.muftatv E/ onProgress: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/videos.txt: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the full command you're using.

Comment: please check i updated my question and help me yet i am stuck

Comment: Confirm that `resultPathVideo` contains a filename with extension mp4 and not just a path.

Comment: I send that argument in cancatvideo methor and in which url contain .mp4 extension also VideoWork.concatVideo(tsFiles_arr_merge,Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Mufta/"+"abc"+".mp4");

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(‌​)+"/Mufta/"+"abc"+".mp4" this is the resultpathvideo string

Comment: This is what ffmpeg sees - `/storage/emulated/0/Mufta/Sila`. No extension here.

Comment: sory my mistake i send it to you updated resultvideopath url but  i showed error on above is old and here is updated error but issue is same waste memory